# Host html pages in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to build a chrome extension with multiple HTML pages linked together.

I couldn't find any way to host HTML pages within it.

Any help on this issue

Thanks

Comment: Please show everything you have tried and you're research and findings in more detail. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's unclear what you want because there is no "hosting" inside the browser: it doesn't have a built-in server. Hint: it may be faster for you to find an existing extension that does what you want, then inspect its source code in crxviewer or devtools.